# How to get implicit and explicit identical value to align when both being mixed in

Tags: scala, traits, composition

Assume the following situation

- I have a trait A and a trait B that both declare a value that has the same name and type.
- A defines the value explicitly, while B defines it implicitly
- A and B are from external libraries and can not be changed. I don't want to fork.
- I want to use both of them in a class C that is in my own code

How can I get them to align inside class C? 
I want B.foo to be the value from A.foo

```
// External code, cant touch
trait A{
  val foo = "boom"
}
trait B{ 
  implicit val foo: String
}

// My class
class C extends A with B {
  //uh oh??
}
```

**Update (with help from Jasper-M)**

```
// External code, cant touch
trait A{
  val foo = "boom"
}
trait B{
  implicit val foo: String

  def implBang()(implicit s: String) = s

  def doTheBang() = implBang()
}

// My class
class C extends B with A {}

new C().doTheBang; // Prints "boom"
```

Now only question remaining, how would I get foo to be in the implicit scope for class C?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you don't want `foo` to be implicit in `C` then `class C extends A with B` just works.

Comment: A gives me a foo, and B requires one to be implicitly defined. However since they have the same name I dont see how I can appoint the value of A.foo to B.foo?

Comment: There is only one `foo` in `class C extends A with B` and it has the value `"ok"`. From the point of view of `B` that `foo` is implicit. Seen from `C` or `A` it is not implicit.

Comment: That sheds some light! How would I get the implicit version in to scope? Doesn't seem to depend on the way I stack the traits?

Comment: From my experiments I think the implicitness is `C` depends on which `foo` has an implementation. The compiler seems to pick the implicitness (or implicity, or... ) of the one that is not abstract. I'll post an answer with a possible workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you can select the implementation you want with `super[Name]`. But for vals that doesn't work [for some reason](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/1938).

```
class C extends A with B {
  override implicit val foo = super[A].foo
  // error: super may not be used on value foo
}
```

So if you really need some implicit `String` in `C` I would suggest just letting linearization do its thing and define another implicit val.

```
class C extends A with B {
  implicit val bar = foo
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the `implicit` variable, like:

```
// My class
class C extends A with B {
  override implicit val foo = "My Value"
}
```

Comment: Ok great, but now how do I get the value from trait A there?

      override implicit val foo = foo 

doesnt work